Is it possible to ask for constructive feedback/peer reviewing of projects in this forum?
I am taking some graphic design courses on Coursera. I can't pay for the full course features, but I would like to complete and share the peer-reviewed activities to get constructive feedback. May I ask for that here?

you can https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcritique%5D+is%3Aq
